# Nginx + php fastcgi unable to open file, permission denied

Tags: php, nginx, permissions, redhat, fastcgi

I am having some permission issues with Nginx and Php fastcgi when trying to get to the php file. I am using 5.5.15 and Nginx 1.6.0 in Redhat 7 .

My php file is very simple for now.

```
<?php
echo "\nscript owner : ".get_current_user()."\n";
$myFile = '/usr/share/nginx/html/test.log';
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can''t open file");
?>
```

Get current user will result in : "myuser"

The error that I am getting is the following:

```
2014/08/26 22:47:14 [error] 6424#0: *16 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP     Warning:  fopen(/usr/share/nginx/html/test.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied     in /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php on line 19" while reading response header from upstream, client: XXXXXX, server: XXXXXXX, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "XXXXXXX"
```

Here is the permissions for the directory /usr/share/nginx( all of the parent directories have x permissions):

```
drwxrwsrwx. 4 myuser myuser 4096 Aug 26 22:32 html
```

Running the following commands:

```
$ ps aux | grep "nginx: worker process"
myuser  6423  0.0  0.3 111228  3880 ?        S    22:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
myuser  6424  0.0  0.5 111228  5428 ?        S    22:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
myuser  6480  0.0  0.0 112640   980 pts/0    R+   22:41   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx: worker process

$ ps aux | grep "php"
myuser 5930  0.0  0.1 128616  1860 pts/0    T    21:09   0:00 vi /etc/php-fpm.conf
myuser 5931  0.0  0.2 128628  2052 pts/0    T    21:09   0:00 vi /etc/php.ini
myuser  5933  0.0  0.1 128616  1864 pts/0    T    21:13   0:00 vi /etc/php-fpm.conf
myuser  5934  0.0  0.1 128616  1860 pts/0    T    21:14   0:00 vi /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
myuser  5935  0.0  0.1 128616  1864 pts/0    T    21:15   0:00 vi /etc/php-fpm.conf
root    6313  0.0  2.4 544732 25208 ?        Ss   22:25   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
myuser  6314  0.0  0.8 544732  8356 ?        S    22:25   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
myuser  6315  0.0  0.8 544732  8328 ?        S    22:25   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
myuser  6316  0.0  0.9 545076  9892 ?        S    22:25   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
myuser  6317  0.0  0.9 544860  9452 ?        S    22:25   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
myuser  6318  0.0  0.9 544860  9212 ?        S    22:25   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
myuser  6483  0.0  0.0 112640   976 pts/0    R+   22:47   0:00 grep --color=auto php
```

My Server looks like the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;       
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;


# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

And in the nginx.config I am using the same user: "user ec2-user;"
I have also changed the /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf file to have the same user and group.

```
user = myuser
group = myuser
```

So, both Nginx and PHP are running on the same user "myuser".
All the directories up to where the log file and the php file are located(/usr/share/nginx/html) have x access and that user has 777 access to that html directory.

Not sure what I am missing. I have been searching online for 2 days now but no luck.

Comment: hey @user1653068, are there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose rights are correct, but you have 3 line of code in test.php, but due to error this is not true :) Check what file you run.

> "in /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php on line 19"

Comment: I actually had empty lines that's why it is saying line 19. In the file line 19 is "$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can''t open file");"